# Design of item listing on sidebar

Tags: interface-design

On the sidebar for a web application I am working on, I have an option to allow users to change their current template.

I think the current design looks ok, but it doesn't really seem engaging or interesting. It doesn't fit into the rest of the design.

What changes can I make to the template listing design to make it fit more into the design. I am working with a little amount of space, but not sure whether to make it look like a icon listing (as it does at the moment) or to just use text.

[image]

Comment: Tip #1: make the template previews bigger. Those are tiny. They should probably take up the full width (not including padding around the sides)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using just the template thumbnails you can use cards with some info. There are many nice UX cards examples on the internet.

> ## What are cards? What are its benefits?
>
> Cards resemble physical cards. They are rectangles including images, texts, links, buttons etc., and are used as a teaser to detailed information. A card consists of multiple containers with one element occupying one container. One container has the image, the second one has the title, third the copy, fourth the link to next page and so on.

[image]

[image]

Definition from [uxplanet.org](https://uxplanet.org/best-practices-for-designing-cards-a19f53cab052)